# HTML a tag redirecting to social channel is blocked

Tags: javascript, html, target

I'd like to redirect user to other website in browser new tab like below.

```js
const redirect = async () => {
  const { link } = await axios.get('https://api.mywebsite.com')
  window.open(link)
}
```

I know it is wrong approach, so I changed to way to redirect. Below is the solution I found.

```js
const redirect = async () => {
  let tab = window.open()

  const { link } = await axios.get('https://api.mywebsite.com')

  tab.location.href = link
}
```

But, still got error. So I replace button tag with a tag.

```
<a href="https://instagram.com/drawbeat_official" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

But got still result.. It's just plain`a` tag. How can I resolve this issue? Looks weird.

I found some warning response header in developer console from `instagram.com`

```
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin-allow-popups;report-to="coop"

-> This document was blocked from loading in an iframe with a sandbox attribute because this document specified a cross-origin opener policy.
```

+++

Is it possible because of some kind of cache?

Comment: Show how you're using the `<a>` tag for this. The error indicates you're trying to put the site into an iframe.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525567/ajax-popup-blocked-in-ie-but-not-in-ff for how to work around the popup blocker when using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar Just <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/CRTNSx6LPZ5/" target="_blank">Join</a>.

I already tried some ways to resolve it, but got same error. I think looks like because of some browser or target server cache..?

Comment: Web sites can block you from putting them inside an iframe. That's what the error indicates.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is not within your A tag or the button, it is in the redirect function. CORS stands for Cross Origin Resource Sharing. When You Request The Content with axios your browser attaches a header called origin. this contains the url the request is issued from. when the server returns the response the browser checks if the origin matches any one of the headers specified in the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin. If Not it does not allow the response to be viewed to be readen by the website. but even if you managed to add your website in the header, it will still not work. when you are getting the requst with the help of axios it returns the html. I suggest using window.location to redirect. For Example:

```
window.location = "https://yourwebsite.com"
```

This Will Do The redirect on the client.

Kamestart

Comment: This will not open the new location in a different tab, it will replace the current tab.

Comment: They're not try to redirect to their website, they're trying to open a new window in with the URL returned by the API.

Answer (score 0):

Some websites of different origin don't allow it due to security reasons related to [Same-origin security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), in that case your browser will block opening these websites on a new tab from your origin (your website URL). By enabling CORS from your server where your website is hosted, can fix the problem.